# Rails 4 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute to_json encodes DateTime incorrectly

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, json, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

The end-game is to have my model read all tables starting with "manager_" and serialize the records as JSON for transmitting to a slave application which will write the JSON strings back into its database as a synchronization procedure.

i.e., DB > JSON > (transmit over web) > JSON > DB

The problem I'm having right at the moment is that the DateTime object is being encoded with a colon within the time zone at the end and mysql is barfing when trying to write the attribute to the db. I've read elsewhere on SO that I need to monkeypatch the method thusly:

```
module ActiveSupport
  class TimeWithZone
    # There shouldn't be a colon in the timezone for storing into the db
    def to_json
      super.gsub(/:(?!.*:)/,'')
    end
  end
end
```

However while this works with calls to Time.zone.now for example, it doesn't work with a straight Time.now and so the records are still being serialized with the colon in the time zone.

What I get: `2014-02-28T20:37:13-05:00`

What I should get: `2014-02-28T20:37:13-0500`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scratch that, when writing to the DB I cannot have the timestamp in that format. The correct format to use is `2014-02-28 20:37:13`.

I had to monkeypatch both TimeWithZone and Time class with the following:

```
def as_json(options=nil)
    return to_s(:db)
end
```

This will affect any other to_json calls not related to db synchronization, so my time stamps will no longer have a time zone but I'm willing to sacrifice this.